# multiple rails app in apache using passenger on centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have been following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6) on how to run a rails app in an apache server. I have successfully made it work but with only 1 rails app running. I tried editing the httpd.conf with 2 virtual hosts.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.42/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so 
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.42 
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1/ruby 

RackEnv development

<VirtualHost *:3000>
 ServerName ***.***.***.***
 # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testapp/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/testapp/public>
 # This relaxes Apache security settings.
 AllowOverride all
 # MultiViews must be turned off.
 Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:3001>
 ServerName ***.***.***.***
 # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testapp2/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/testapp2/public>
 # This relaxes Apache security settings.
 AllowOverride all
 # MultiViews must be turned off.
 Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but it seems only port 3000 is working.

Comment: Try `rails s -p 3001` for 2nd app. And check if you can access it on port `3000`

Comment: what do you mean access the 2nd app on port `3000`?

Comment: oh! typo.. try to aceess 2nd app on `3001`

Comment: => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-09-09 17:10:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-09-09 17:10:54] INFO  ruby 2.1.1 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-09-09 17:10:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12643 port=3001

still cant access the server with port `3001`

Comment: Gotcha! ask your network admin to make port 3001 accessible. It must not be accessible

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you have the other server set up on **port 3001**

---

**Port**

The problem you'll have is that you're capturing the same request (to same domain / IP), except listening on different ports. If you want to access the different sites, therefore, you have to access by the ports you define.

```
#app1 -> ***.***.***.***:3000
#app2 -> ***.***.***.***:3001
```

This should give you the ability to access your Rails apps respective to your apache implementation.

--

**VirtualHosts**

If I were you, I'd either create a virtualhost with a directory setup:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName [ip]

   # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
   DocumentRoot /apps/public

   #Other App
   Alias /app1 /apps/app1/public
   <Location /reach>
      PassengerAppRoot /apps/app1/public
      RackEnv production
      RackBaseURI /app1
   </Location>

   #Other App
   Alias /app2 /apps/app2/public
   <Location /apps>
      PassengerAppRoot /apps/app2/public
      RackEnv production
      RackBaseURI /app2
      PassengerFriendlyErrorPages off
   </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

This will give you a much simpler way to handle the incoming requests:

```
***.***.***.*** -> IP index
***.***.***.***/app1 -> application 1
***.***.***.***/app2 -> application 2
```

I'd be much more tempted to use the above setup than your own.

Further, you may also wish to actually deploy separate virtual hosts for your applications. The above example details how you'd introduce different `directories` for your different apps - if you'd prefer to create different virtualhosts, here's what you can do:

```
#etc/apache2/sites-available/default (standard site - I'd recommend static)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


#etc/apache2/sites-available/app1
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias yourdomain.com

    DocumentRoot /apps/app1/public
        <Directory /apps/app1/public>
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to symlink these to your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder:

```
> $ ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/app1 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app1
```